# Why is my frame not resizing?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe, contentpane

When you choose a state, the frame's content pane removes its components. Then depending on the state you chose, another class takes the content pane and adds onto it. After doing so, the frame gets packed to resize accordingly.

I want free control over whats in the Frame, such as being able to put panels side by side, above one another, ect.. so I really don't want to use CardLayout. (I'd much rather have 1 panel handle both loginscreen and chat. Then, be able to display another panel next to that one).

I'm using the JFrame's content pane for my login and chat screen, but when I run my code, I get a small frame (has SOME size, but hardly any) that's white on the inside.

1. show frame
2. switch to chat
3. remove everything on pane (currently nothing)
4. add components onto pane
5. pack frame so it can size accordingly to the pane
6. revalidate if needed (not sure when I need to revalidate or not)

Please tell me what I'm doing wrong, and maybe guide me in the right direction.
PS: There are no errors

EDIT: The only thing I can think of is that since I'm passing `frame.getContentPane()` through the method, and methods are pass-by-value, the actual reference to `frame.getContentPane()` might not be noticing the changes I'm asking for. But then I don't know why the inside of the frame would be white (as if my JTextArea tried rendering), and there's padding on the inside of the frame, so there has to be something happening..

Main.java:

```
package main;

import ui.Frame;

public class Main {
    public static Frame frame = new Frame();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        frame.show();
        frame.switchState(State.chat);

    }

    public static enum State {
        login, chat;
    }
}
```

Frame.java:

```
package ui;

import main.Main.State; 
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Frame {
        private Panel currentpanel; //from package ui, not AWT
        private ChatPanel chatpanel = new ChatPanel();

        private JFrame frame;
        public Frame() {
            frame = new JFrame();
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setResizable(false);
        }

        public void show() {
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }

        public void switchState(State state) {
            frame.removeAll();

            switch(state) {
                 case chat:
                currentpanel = chatpanel;
                currentpanel.addComponentsTo(frame.getContentPane());
                break;
            }
            frame.pack();
            frame.revalidate();
        }
    }
```

Panel.java:

```
package ui;

import java.awt.Container;

public interface Panel {
    public void addComponentsTo(Container pane);
}
```

ChatPanel.java:

```
package ui;

import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;

import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class ChatPanel implements Panel {
    private JTextArea toparea = new JTextArea();
    private JTextArea bottomarea = new JTextArea();

    @Override
    public void addComponentsTo(Container pane) {
        pane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
        pane.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.ipadx = 450;
        gbc.ipady = 350;
        pane.add(toparea, gbc);

        gbc.gridy = 1;
        gbc.ipady = 100;
        pane.add(bottomarea);
    }
}
```

Comment: Class `LoginPanel ` is not supplied, the code won't compile. Also the call `frame.switchState(...)` claims that Frame#switchState is not visible (and indeed it's not declared public). Also note that you should not name your classes after already existing classes like Panel and Frame, use your own names or it will cause confusion (what with your Panel being an interface and in AWT it's a class).

Comment: @user1803551 The code has been fixed. LoginPanel has been removed, and method is public. Sorry about that. There was a lot of code I had to remove in order to simplify this, so there might have been some issues that didn't relate to my problem, but I fixed it. Minor mistakes

Comment: Alright, good. Now how do you make a switch call on a State object? switch does not support receiving an instance of State as it's argument.

Comment: Huh? If you're talking about the warning on the switch statement, it gives that because I don't have a default case. The switching system works fine. Make a small demo for yourself and see with print statements.

Comment: My compiler insists on "Cannot switch on a value of type Main.State." and will not run it. I will just use if-else instead of switch.

Comment: To be honest CardLayout seems like a perfect solution, but you can do it your way which is less efficient and less reliable. I'll post the corrections soon.

Comment: @AndrewThompson That's as minimal as it gets. I was removing the `JRootPane` instead of the components on the contentpane, and I was removing too early.

Answer (score 0):

I know that can be quite frustrating.

have you tried calling

```
pack(); or repaint();
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. It was calling `frame.removeAll();` before adding anything to it.

When I tried `if(frame.getComponents().length > 0)`, it still triggered `removeAll()`, but the problem wasn't fixed. Seeing how I haven't added anything yet, I checked to see what the component was (by printing out the object), and it was a `JRootPane`.

After that, I tried printing out `frame.getContentPane().getComponents().length`, it gave me 0 as expected.

Long story short: This is how `switchPanel(State state)` should look:

```
    public void switchState(State state) {
        if(frame.getContentPane().getComponents().length > 0)
             frame.removeAll();

        switch(state) {
             case chat:
                 currentpanel = chatpanel;
                 currentpanel.addComponentsTo(frame.getContentPane());
                 break;
        }
        frame.pack();
        frame.revalidate();
    }
```

Comment: You should call `frame.getContentPane().removeAll();`. Calling `removeAll` on the JFrame removes its root pane.

Comment: Don't use `JFrame#removeAll`, it removes the `JRootPane` which is used to manage the content (and other things) from the frame, instead, use a `CardLayout` or if you must, use `JFrame#getContentPane().removeAll()`.  This is not a viable solution nor is it a good recommendation

Comment: Using `CardLayout` insists that I create more than 2 `JPanel`s to switch between the two. Doing it my way give the same results, just using the same panel. Another downside to making `JFrame`s layout `CardLayout` is that I would need: 1. `A Container` to hold my other panels; 2. A Container for my Login; 3. A Container for my Chat; 4. I'm not sure if I could put 2 panels side-by-side while using `CardLayout`

Answer (score 0):

*NOTE: I still recommend CardLayout, but if you insists in dynamically setting the frame's content pane the here it is.*

The frame class

```
public class SwitchingFrame extends JFrame {

    public static enum State {ONE, TWO}
    private PanelONE panel1 = new PanelONE();
    private PanelTWO panel2 = new PanelTWO();

    public SwitchingFrame() {

        getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public void switchState(State state) {

        setVisible(false);
        getContentPane().removeAll();
        if (state.equals(State.ONE))
            getContentPane().add(panel1, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        else
            getContentPane().add(panel2, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

The two panel classes which are switched

```
public class PanelONE extends JPanel {

    public PanelONE() {

        add(new JLabel("ONE"));
    }
}
```

---

```
public class PanelONE extends JPanel {

    public PanelTWO() {

        add(new JLabel("TWO"));
    }
}
```

The main method which includes buttons to simulate changing the panels

```
public class TestSwitchingFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final SwitchingFrame sframe = new SwitchingFrame();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JButton b1 = new JButton("ONE");
        b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                sframe.switchState(SwitchingFrame.State.ONE);
            }
        });
        JButton b2 = new JButton("TWO");
        b2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                sframe.switchState(SwitchingFrame.State.TWO);
            }
        });
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        frame.getContentPane().add(b1);
        frame.getContentPane().add(b2);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

You do not need (not should) write your own interface (Panel). Your two panels should extend JPanel and set within the frames content pane. Your frame should extend JFrame and does not need to override its `show` method (let Swing do it for you). The specific implementation of the `switchState` function should eventually depend on the end result you want. There are similar ways to accomplish almost the same result.

Comment: I don't want 2 new JPanel objects. I want to use the same pane (as already stated). I already got it to work, look at the answer I posted

Comment: The way you did it is not good unfortunately, as Radiodef and MadProgrammer noted. Besides, you already have 2 panels: your chat and your login panels are two different components you set according to the State.

Comment: I understand that trying to recreate something Oracle has already done (`CardLayout`) isn't praised, but it seems to be more efficient than if I were to use `CardLayout`. My `ChatPanel` and `LoginPanel` aren't really Panels, but are closer to being Component Holders. I'm using 1 frame, and adding/removing already existing components to that frame depending on state. All my Components are kept and not reinitialized (like CardLayout), so I don't see any problem in doing it this way

Comment: "it seems to be more efficient than if I were to use CardLayout" actually the opposite - CardLayout is built for this situation - it is efficient in terms of performance and reliable. You call frame.removeAll() instead of working with the content pane, which can only bring trouble in the future. These kinds of manipulation are not robust and definitely not performance efficient. I also don't know what a Component Holder is, but I am willing to guarantee  that there is a better way to do what you want to do.

Comment: You can't put panels next to each other with CardLayout though.. That's a big flaw in the situation, next to all the panes needed. I'm removing all the contents from the pane so I can add more to it. I see that as purely working with the content pane instead of using a layout to handle what I want to do